# Simple proof of "$a$ and $a^{-1}$ have the same number of conjugates"

Tags: group-theory, alternative-proof

I recently had to give a proof of this, I gave a correct proof but I feel that it was overly complicated, so the question here is "Find a simpler proof (one that belongs in "the book")".

---

Question: "Given a group $G$ and $a\in G$, prove that $a$ and $a^{-1}$ have the same number of distinct conjugates."

My answer (just a sketch):

Take $Cl(a)$ (conjugacy class of a) and $Cl(a^{-1})$, show that $x\in Cl(a) \iff x^{-1}\in Cl(a^{-1})$ (call this Statement 1).

Form the function $g$ on a set $S\subset G$, $g(S)=\{s^{-1}|s\in S\}$. Show that this is an involution, and thus a bijection.

Show that $Cl(a^{-1})=g(Cl(a))$ (by proving both $Cl(a^{-1})\subset g(Cl(a))$ and $g(Cl(a))\subset Cl(a^{-1})$ , by using Statement 1).

By definition of "same cardinality" ($\equiv$ there exists a bijection between them), conclude $Cl(a^{-1})=g(Cl(a)) \implies |Cl(a^{-1})|=|Cl(a)|$.

---

This took about 2.5 pages to fully explicate. Surely there must be a more concise proof for such a simple question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $G$ act on itself by conjugation. The stabiliser of $a$ is $C(a)$, the centraliser of $a$, and $C(a) = C(a^{-1})$, so the number of conjugates of $a^{-1}$ is $(G:C(a^{-1})) = (G:C(a))$, which is the number of conjugates of $a$.

Comment: I had totally forgotten that the number of conjugates of $a$ is $(G:C(a))$. Thankfully it seems I was able to synthesize my way around this forgetfulness!

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're overthinking. `;-)`

The map $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ induces a map $\operatorname{Cl}(a)\to\operatorname{Cl}(a^{-1})$.

Indeed, if $x=gag^{-1}$ is a conjugate of $a$, then $x^{-1}=ga^{-1}g^{-1}$ is a conjugate of $a^{-1}$.

Call $f_a$ the map above. Then $f_{a^{-1}}\colon \operatorname{Cl}(a^{-1})\to\operatorname{Cl}(a)$ has the property that $f_{a^{-1}}\circ f_a$ is the identity on $\operatorname{Cl}(a)$. Similarly, $f_{a}\circ f_{a^{-1}}$ is the identity on $\operatorname{Cl}(a^{-1})$.

Note that this doesn't require $G$ to be finite.

Comment: Isn't this exactly my proof?

Comment: @Justaskin_ Yes and no; yours is badly written (the part about $g$ is very confused). Surely this doesn't require two and a half pages.

Comment: If I just specify that $g:\mathcal{P}(G)\to\mathcal{P}(G)$ that should properly define the function g, which is easily shown to be an involution... True, a full page of my answer was proving $Cl(a^{-1})\subset g(Cl(a))$ and $g(Cl(a))\subset Cl(a^{-1})$ , which could have been eliminated by showing (analogously to what you did above) that g(g(S)) is the identity on $\mathcal{P}(G)$ . That may have been a tedious path to take, but I wouldn't say that makes the proof "badly written"...

Comment: @Justaskin_ There's no need whatsoever of a function $\mathcal{P}(G)\to\mathcal{P}(G)$. That's where you are confusing things.

Comment: @Justaskin_ The fact that $g(Cl(a))=Cl(a^{-1})$ has nothing to do with cardinality of the sets. The map $A\mapsto G\setminus A$ is an involution of $\mathcal{P}(G)$, but it's unlikely that $|A|=|G\setminus A|$, is it?

Comment: wow, this really was very confused. I think I now can only leave it at that, learn and move on...